# Dictionary:Get(): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Here i am trying to append in a dict. if key exist or else create a new list and then append. 
Using get() function.

But its giving error of 'NONE Type objects.

```
class Solution:

    def solve(self, A, B):
        save_x={}
        save_y={}
        l=len(A)
        for i in range(l):
            save_x[A[i]]=save_x.get(A[i],[]).append(B[i])
            save_y[B[i]]=save_y.get(B[i],[]).append(A[i])

        print(save_x,save_y)
```

Comment: can you show ho did you run your function?

Comment: @kederrac It is something like this
s=Solution()
s.solve([1,1,2,2],[1,2,1,2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) doesn't return something (returns `None`), you can fix your issue changing the `for` loop with:

```
for i in range(l):
    save_x[A[i]] = save_x.get(A[i], []) + [B[i]]
    save_y[B[i]] = save_y.get(B[i], []) + [A[i]]
```

this version is a bit slow since it is creating a new list at each iteration

or you could use `dict.setdefault` and update a key if already exists (a bit faster):

```
for i in range(l):
    save_x.setdefault(A[i], []).append(B[i])
    save_y.setdefault(B[i], []).append(A[i])
```

the best option will be to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict


save_x = defaultdict(list)
save_y = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    save_x[a].append(b)
    save_y[b].append(a)
```